Axis of a projection with center $Q$ on a bisector of one of the angles formed by $l_1,l_2$

Let $l_1,l_2$ be distinct lines intersecting at the point $P$. Let $m_1$ be the bisector of one of the angles formed by the two lines $l_1$, $l_2$ and $Q \neq P$ a point on $m_1$. Let $Q^{\vee}:l_1 \to l_2$ be the projection of center $Q$. Show that the axis of the homography is the bisector of the other angle formed by $l_1, l_2$.

Firstly, I thought about a perspective $f$ with axis $m_2$, that is the bisector of the other angle formed by the two lines $l_1$, $l_2$ and center $P$ that maps $Q$ to the point of infinity of the line $m_1$, after applying $f$, the projection of center $f(Q)$ would map a point $A$ in $l_1$ to the intersection between the parallel line to $m_1$ passing through $A$ and $l_2$ and it'd be a rotation that maps $l_1$ to $l_2$, so its axis would be the bisector that I'm interested in; now I'm interested to know if I could show that the axis of the homography is the bisector of the other angle formed by $l_1, l_2$ by this argument; any suggestions?
